# can't get writing to an output file going

Tags: c++

I'm asking another question here again. I'm trying to write my variables after the wilks calculation back into an output file that my program creates. I've set up the table formatting which all works but I can't get any of my data written back into the file. Right now I've got the outFile statements within the loop. Can somebody point me in the right direction to get this working.

```
    outFile.open("Final output.txt");
    // print the report title and column headings
    outFile << "                               Meet Report" << endl;
    outFile << "Gender      Weight Class(LBS)    Squat   Bench   Deadlift    Wilks" << endl;
    outFile << "---------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

    // serves as the first input for sentinel loop and determining the correct formula for wilks calculation
    cout << "Please enter your gender (male/female, or e to end): ";
    cin >> gender;
    cout << endl;

    while (gender != "male" && gender != "female")
    {
        cout << "Incorrect input. Please try again." << endl;
        cout << "Please enter your gender (male/female, or e to end): ";
        cin >> gender;
        cout << endl;
    }

    while (gender == "male")
        {
            cout << "Please use kilograms (KG) for all inputs." << endl;
            cout << "Enter your bodyweight: ";
            cin >> weight;
            cout << "Enter your final bench press attempt: ";
            cin >> bench;
            cout << "Enter your final squat attempt: ";
            cin >> squat;
            cout << "Enter your final deadlift attempt: ";
            cin >> deadlift;

            total = bench + squat + deadlift;

            wilksCalc = 500 / (A_MEN + B_MEN * (weight) + C_MEN * (weight * weight) + D_MEN * (weight * weight * weight) +
            E_MEN * (weight * weight * weight * weight) + F_MEN * (weight * weight * weight * weight * weight));

            wilks = wilksCalc * total;

            cout << wilks;
            cout << endl;

            outFile << left << setw(21) << gender;
            outFile << weight;
            outFile << right << setw(11) << squat;
            outFile << right << setw(11) << bench;
            outFile << right << setw(11) << deadlift;
            outFile << right << setw(11) << wilks;

        if (gender == "female")
        {
            cout << "Please use kilograms (KG) for all inputs." << endl;
            cout << "Enter your bodyweight: ";
            cin >> weight;
            cout << "Enter your final bench press attempt: ";
            cin >> bench;
            cout << "Enter your final squat attempt: ";
            cin >> squat;
            cout << "Enter your final deadlift attempt: ";
            cin >> deadlift;

            total = bench + squat + deadlift;

            wilksCalc = 500 / (A_WOMEN + B_WOMEN * (weight) + C_WOMEN * (weight * weight) + D_WOMEN * (weight * weight * weight) +
            E_WOMEN * (weight * weight * weight * weight) + F_WOMEN * (weight * weight * weight * weight * weight));

            wilks = wilksCalc * total;

            cout << wilks;
            cout << endl;

            outFile << left << setw(21) << gender;
            outFile << weight;
            outFile << right << setw(11) << squat;
            outFile << right << setw(11) << bench;
            outFile << right << setw(11) << deadlift;
            outFile << right << setw(11) << wilks;
        }
    }

    outFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if `gender == "female"` that `while (gender == "male")`  loop will not execute in the first place. So checking for `if (gender == "female")` inside the while loop will not accomplish anything as it is always `false`.

Comment: `while (gender == "male")` probably should be `if (gender == "male")`. Then you need to take `if (gender == "female")` out of it.

Comment: Almost all the code in the male and female blocks is the same. The only difference is the formula for calculating `wiksCalc`. So that should be the only thing you put in the `if`.